# Kotlin put generic type object into specific hashmap

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I'm doing small library in Kotlin which handles presenter during configuration changed. I create presenter store class where I going to keep the presenters. I use generic class but I have problem but maybe I'll show you the code.

```
interface AbstractStore {
    fun clear()
    fun <V : AbstractView> put(key: String, presenter: Presenter<V>)
    fun <V : AbstractView> get(key: String): Presenter<V>? 
}
```

and implementation of Abstract Store

```
class PresenterStore : AbstractStore {

    private val mMap = HashMap<String, Presenter<AbstractView>>()

    override fun <V : AbstractView> put(key: String, presenter: Presenter<V>) {
        mMap[key] = presenter   // problem is here. I can't do this in that way.
    }

    override fun <V : AbstractView> get(key: String): Presenter<V>? {
        return mMap[key]
    }

    /**
     * Clears internal storage that Presenters are no longer used.
     */
    override fun clear() {
        mMap.forEach { (_, presenter) -> presenter.onDestory() }
        mMap.clear()
    }
}
```

I got problem with the `put` method. The message what I get:

```
Error:(12, 10) Type inference failed: Cannot infer type parameter V in operator inline fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V#1 (type parameter of kotlin.collections.set)>.set(key: K, value: V#1): Unit
None of the following substitutions
receiver: MutableMap<String, Presenter<AbstractView>>  arguments: (String,Presenter<AbstractView>)
receiver: MutableMap<String, Presenter<V#2 (type parameter of com.xxxx.mvp.presenter.PresenterStore.put)>>  arguments: (String,Presenter<V#2>)
can be applied to
receiver: HashMap<String, Presenter<AbstractView>>  arguments: (String,Presenter<V#2>)
```

I don't get it what is going on but If I change it the method to

`mMap[key] = presenter as Presenter<AbstractView>` then works with warning

```
Unchecked cast: Presenter<V> to Presenter<AbstractView>
```

Is there any possibilities to keep method without casting? Why Kotlin doesn't know that Presenter is a generic class with subtype of AbstractView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of making the two methods independently generic, use a class type parameter like so:

```
interface AbstractStore <V : AbstractView> {
    fun clear()
    fun put(key: String, presenter: Presenter<V>)
    fun get(key: String): Presenter<V>? 
}
```

Then, in the implementation, define a concrete type:

```
class PresenterStore : AbstractStore<ConcreteView> {

    override fun put(key: String, presenter: Presenter<ConcreteView>) {
        mMap[key] = presenter
    }

    override fun get(key: String): Presenter<ConcreteView>? {
        return mMap[key]
    }

    private val mMap = HashMap<String, Presenter<ConcreteView>>()
}
```

Now it works and is completely type safe.

Comment: Thx. The simple the best.